# Use SQL Workbench to read a variable from a file

Tags: postgresql, sql-workbench-j

UPDATE: in the workbench/J log file I am seeing this error:

```
ERROR Variable names may only contain characters (a-z, A-Z), numbers and underscores
```

I'm sure this is what is causing my process to fail, but I have no idea why because my variables are named appropriately.  I've tried renaming them a few times just in case and the same thing happens.

ORIGINAL POST:

I am working on an automated process to dump the contents of a Postgres query to a text file and FTP it to someone.  The process I have been using successfully is a windows batch script that runs SQL Workbench to run the query and write the entire contents of the table to a text file and FTP it.

Now I want to be able to use WBVarDef to load a variable from a text file and use it in my query.  For reference, the variable is the unique id of the last record that was FTPed.  This is the code i have:

```
WBVarDef -variable=id -contentFile=id.txt;
WBVardef today=@"select to_char(current_date,'mmddyyyy')"; 
WBExport -type=text
-file='c:/CLP/FTP/$[today]circ_trans.txt' 
-delimiter='|' 
-quoteAlways=true 
-lineEnding=crlf 
-encoding=utf8; 


SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  transactions
WHERE 
  transactions.id > $[id]
ORDER BY
  transactions.id;
```

The only thing new here is the reference to the text file that contains the id on the first line.  This completely breaks the process but as far as I can tell, I am using this according to the SQL Workbench documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this one out.  I was running an older version of workbench that did not support this functionality.  Now that I upgraded to build 119 this is working.  I'm having other issues but that's a different story....